# GnuPlot: Write Some text in the middle of Boxes

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I'm trying to write at the middle of Boxes of of plot (plotting through gnu plot), but cannot find some elegant way. It is tedious to find the middle points of all boxes manually. Please guide me to figure it out.
[image: Here at the position of circles, I want to add some text, vertically]

Comment: Use e.g `plot with labels`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Christoph mentioned in the comments, `plot ... w labels` is one of the options. The only extra "ingredient" consists in calculating the position of the labels. One might proceed for example as:

```
set terminal pngcairo
set output 'fig.png'

fName='test.dat'

bw = 0.9

yMin = 50
yMax = 130

xMin = 2
xMax = 15

set boxwidth bw

set xr [xMin - bw/2:xMax + bw/2]
set yr [yMin:yMax]

#scale 0 makes sure that the tic marks don't "show up"
set format x "1 %.0f"
set xtics 2,1,15 rotate by -15 scale 0

set ytics 50,10,130 scale 0

set ylabel "TODO"
set xlabel "TODO"

set key top right

#place the labels in the "middle" with respect to the
#minimum on the y-axis
p \
    100 t "Todo" lc rgb "black" dt 3, \
    fName u 1:2 w boxes t "TODO" lc rgb "black", \
    fName u 1:(($2-yMin)/2+yMin):(sprintf("%.0f", $2)) w labels t '' tc rgb 'dark-red'
```

This produces:
[image]

assuming data file `test.dat` as:

```
2  100
3  75
4  74
5  76
6  74
7  78
8  92
9  98
10  75
11  105
12  118
13  120
14  122
15  122
```